# FileZilla stomps all over rbash and scponly

Tags: ssh, ftp, scp, filezilla

Pretty straightforward question: I've got a stock Ubuntu install on a server and I'm trying to only allow certain users to scp files to their own home directories. I read up on rbash and scponly for doing this job, made the required changes to /etc/passwd, and verified that they were working correctly when connecting directly in a terminal via ssh or scp. However, when Filezilla logs in as any of these users, it's able to prance around ls'ing and cd'ing to its heart's content, and I can't figure out why. I've ensured there isn't an FTP daemon running on the server (therefore, as far as I know, forcing Filezilla to connect via SSH and load the shell specified for the user), and beyond that I've got nothing. Help appreciated.

Comment: How are you configuring filezilla when connecting (specifically what protocol)? FTP or SFTP?  You mention SCP as well, which is unusual, since Filezilla does not support SCP . . .

Comment: Does it not? I'm not specifying FTP or SFTP in Filezilla when I connect, only port 22, but it seems to think it's initiating an SFTP connection when I do so. WinSCP also ignores rbash/scponly restrictions when I explicitly specify SCP, so I think something else might be going on here... again, ssh'ing in a terminal behaves as it should.